# Multiple cubes as just one object?

Tags: objects

I'm new to Blender, and am following this tutorial on how to create a nighttime cityscape:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygGQaQld3mc&t=140s

At around 02:20, he is able to duplicate a lot of cubes but keep them all as part of one object. I was wondering how you would go about duplicating an object but still keep everything as what would appear to be one cube object. I've tried every hotkey I can find to do with duplicating, but all of them seem to create a brand new object, which isn't what I want. I'm currently running Blender 2.82, so maybe it's an outdated thing? I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to accomplish is achieved in **Edit Mode.** You can enter the dropdown menu in the menus section of your header, or press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Enter Edit Mode, select all the vertices of the cube, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate.

[image]

Ian Hubert's tutorials are for intermediate users. He operates under the assumption that you are already familiar with the basics of Blender. I recommend following a beginner-friendly tutorial series, then continuing where you left off.

Comment: Thanks! Really big help :)

Comment: There is also the `CTRL+J` shortcut for joining separate objects into 1 singular mesh. Handy for if you wish to stay out of edit-mode and only stay in object-mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is because he is in **Edit Mode** and he is duplicating geometry (groups of faces, edges, vertices) instead of duplicating an object which represents the geometry plus a set of additional information like local coordinate system, modifiers applied etc.

The *IanHubert* [duplicated](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/duplicate.html) geometry, while you [duplicated](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/duplication.html) an object. Open both links to see the difference.

> This tool simply duplicates the **selected elements**, without creating any connections with the rest of the **mesh** (unlike extrude, for example), and places the duplicate at the location of the original.

vs

> This will create a visually-identical **copy** of the selected **object**(s)[...] This copy is a **new object**, which shares some data-blocks with the original object (by default, all the materials, textures, and F-curves), but which has copied others, like the mesh, for example